# What are network errors on munin graphs?

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, munin

I have an VPS running OpenVPN server, that also does have munin installed for monitorig (I've installed it not because it's a real need, but because all these graphs looks cool).

At first I've noticed that sometimes there is big amount of errors on eth0 and was like ehh, that's probably because of UDP being used as protocol for OpenVPN, nothing interesting. But after some time I see on week graph that these errors are in [strong pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoUxd.png) of spikes overnight each day. During that time there is almost [no traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i95z3.png) to/from server.  And there is [graph overlayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyfOu.png) (probably not scaled properly though)

So, my question is what this error count represent, and how come they occur in such pattern/spikes overnight when there is least ammount of traffic, if any?

Note: I know that I haven't provided any actual information for answering second part of question, but this doesn't seem to harm server performance in any way, so I just would be happy just to know potential source of errors (and where to look for debug info in future, if there is any (place to look for, obviously)).